# How can I keep the old dark theme in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2022, dark-theme

VS2022 comes with a new higher-contrast dark theme.

If I prefer the old dark theme (from VS2019), how can I use it in VS2022?

Answer (score 3):

The dark theme from VS2019 is available as an extension on the Visual Studio marketplace here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DarkTheme2019

Once installed you can select it from here:

[image]